# Debugging a 3.1.2. device from xcode 3.2.3

Tags: iphone

A versioning issue here.

We have an application built with xcode 3.2.3 with the iOS 4.0 SDK, but with deployment target set to 3.0 so it will still run on older iPhones.

The program is crashing, so we want to debug.  Getting the standard "The Info.plist for application at /Users/robbonner/Desktop/Eventful.0.8.1 2/build/Debug-iphoneos/Eventful.app specifies a minimum OS version of 4.0, which is too high to be installed on iPhone"

No option to select a build target of 3.1.? anymore.

Funny thing is that the plist does not control this, or I am not aware of a setting,  all of the build settings are in the target configuration.

So, has anyone debugged on older equipment using iOS 4.0 and lived to tell about it?

Comment: To update, the app does install on the 3.1.3 phone, just crashes which is the issue we are trying to debug.  Runs great on iOS 4.

iPhone OS Deployment Target is set to 3.0, so not sure where it thinks we are set to only allow 4.0.

Comment: The Info.plist that is being referred to is in the bundle of your build application.  You can find that at the above path, and if you look at this property list you should see a `MinimumOSVersion` field.  If this is set at 4.0 or above, check the deployment target settings throughout your application.

Answer (score 2):

Change your "iPhone OS Deployment Target"  to IPhone OS 3.1.2

in your Target "app" Build Properties. [image]

Comment: Thanks, the iPhone deployment target is already set to 3.0.  Just tried to be more specific with 3.1.2 and 3.1.3, same issue.